# Reading xml and storing values as a string in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I m new in Android development and never been in JAVA before.

With online tutorials and stackoverflow help I managed to generate a list with XML,

Now I m making it work like if I clicked on list item, it will open other activity.

With php I managed to generate xml I want on request but now in android I want that single entry XML

```
<item name="something"><description>Item description</description></item>
```

like this. But I'm not sure how can I read this remote xml and store values as a string

`String name = Name attribite value` & same for description.

Comment: consider using JSON instead of XML. http://www.json.org/xml.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use a parser like as Pullparser, Saxparser or something what you need.

You can follow the following:  [Parsing example](http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94)

Answer (score 0):

Make one SOAP Web service and call it from Android application. Please find tutorial here
Regarding SOAP:- http://suda.co.uk/publications/MSc/brian.suda.thesis.pdf
And regarding how to use with Android:- http://androidtestexample.blogspot.in/2012/02/soap.html